# How to order posts of a custom post type by date DESC in dashboard Admin?

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, date

I created a new post type named "Video".

When I create post for the post type, posts is ordered by `title ASC`.

**Is it possible to order posts by date DESC please ?**

```
register_post_type('Videos', array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x('Videos', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Video', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Ajouter', 'Video'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Ajouter une video'),
        'edit_item' => __('Éditer une video'),
        'new_item' => __('Nouvelle video'),
        'view_item' => __('Voir le lien de la video'),
        //'search_items' => __(' Video'),
        'menu_name' => 'Video'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'video'),
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor' => false,
        'excerpt' => false,
        'trackbacks' => false,
        'custom-fields',
        'comments' => false,
        'revisions' => false,
        'thumbnail' => false,
        'author' => false,
        'page-attributes' => false,
    ),
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
   )
 );
```

Comment: Please add the code where you output the posts, you don't add the order_by parameter where you register the post_typ only when you query the posts

Comment: Oh sorry, I would like to add the order_by in the Wordpress Admin

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Alright, You can just hook into the filter [pre_get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and check [is_admin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin).
Put this in your theme or plugin:

```
function wpse_81939_post_types_admin_order( $wp_query ) {
  if (is_admin()) {

    // Get the post type from the query
    $post_type = $wp_query->query['post_type'];

    if ( $post_type == 'Videos') {

      $wp_query->set('orderby', 'date');

      $wp_query->set('order', 'DESC');
    }
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'wpse_81939_post_types_admin_order');
```

I also would shange the post_type "Videos" to lowercase like "video".

Comment: Okay, thanks Pontus ! I'll try this. **But why is this not set by default ?** Because for "Posts" is already set by "orderby DESC"

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: it's not by default, coz it's set to "Name" in alphabetical order by default (or slug i guess)

Answer (score 9):

The example above disables the ordering feature by clicking columns.

Sortable & for multiple custom post types:

```
function wpse_819391_post_types_admin_order( $wp_query ) {
  if ( is_admin() && !isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ) {     
    // Get the post type from the query
    $post_type = $wp_query->query['post_type'];
    if ( in_array( $post_type, array('videos','news','text') ) ) {
      $wp_query->set('orderby', 'date');
      $wp_query->set('order', 'DESC');
    }
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'wpse_819391_post_types_admin_order');
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a bit different approach:

```
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_posts_list'); 

    function filter_posts_list($query)  {
        //$pagenow holds the name of the current page being viewed
         global $pagenow, $typenow;  
        if(current_user_can('edit_posts') && ('edit.php' == $pagenow))  { 
            //global $query's set() method for setting
            $query->set('orderby', 'date');
            $query->set('order', 'desc');
        }
    }
```