# Sort posts in dashboard using custom field; also include posts where field isn't set

Tags: wp-query, meta-query, pre-get-posts

I'm using a pre_get_posts filter found on [this question thread here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81939/how-to-order-posts-of-a-custom-post-type-by-date-desc-in-dashboard-admin), to sort a custom post type in the dashboard:

```
function xyz_event_sort_order( $wp_query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        $post_type = $wp_query->query['post_type'];
        if ( $post_type == 'event' ) {
            $wp_query->set( 'meta_key', 'x_start_date' );
            $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'x_start_date' );
            $wp_query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'xyz_event_sort_order' );
```

The filter sorts the events as expected, but events where the custom field has not been set (old events imported from another WP install) will, obviously, no longer show at all. I'm trying to do a meta_query that uses EXISTS and NOT EXISTS and still sorts by the meta_key specified above, but have had no luck.

Anybody know how I might also include events where *x_start_date* is missing and then add date as a second orderby option like: `( 'orderby', 'x_start_date date' );`

Comment: what is the save date format ?

Comment: @Shazzad, the format is 'Y-m-d'. The sort works correctly, it just needs to be modified to include cases where the key is not set. Maybe a meta_query with two different arrays using compare?